# Entering into a loop only once and then after some time

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, global-variables

well i've a loop in which i want to enter only for once when condition is satisfied and then again it should enter after a variable value gets changed.

```
class OMS:

    timeframe_check = 1
    
    def upside_ex(self,tickers):
        for ticker in tickers:
            try:
                order_placed = False
                    if self.timeframe_check == latest_time:
                       if order_check_1st_sca == True and not order_placed:
                          self.PlaceOptionOrderBuy(tickers,"buy",quantity)
                          order_placed = True
                       if order_check_1st == True and not order_placed:
                           self.PlaceOptionOrderBuy(tickers,"buy",quantity)
                           order_placed = True
                    else:
                        order_placed = False
                        self.timeframe_check += 1
                        print(self.timeframe_check , "this is timeframe_check from else which got incremented")
                        break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
```

i want to enter inside the inside the if loop when both timeframe_check and latest_time are equal and make the order_placed as true so that it'll not enter inside the loop until and unless it's made false again.

But the issue is in the first iteration it's entering the if loop but when the second iteration comes it only enters the else loop and does the increment. after increment it should again enter the if loop but it's not doing it as expected.

Because at the same time it's shows timeframe_check as 1 and also inside the else loop timeframe_chcek as 2 after incremented but then why it's not entering the if loop after the incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

you using `break`. So after getting incremental you are breaking out of the loop that's why next time loop doesn't iterate. You can use `pass` instead.

Comment: i did as you said but it's showing me the same result @Rohit Rajput.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).